# Vim regex: add line above all lines not starting with "#"

Tags: regex, vim, replace, line, regex-group

I have a text file with a structure like this:

```
The quick  
#a comment
brown 
fox jumps  
#another comment
over  
the 
lazy
#yet another comment
dog
```

So each line either contains "normal" text or a comment starting with "#". 
I want this text to be replaced using regex, so that each "text"-line gets a comment line above it. The result should be something like:

```
#auto comment
The quick  
#a comment
brown 
#auto comment
fox jumps  
#another comment
over  
#auto comment
the 
#auto comment
lazy
#yet another comment
dog
```

However, I'm not able to create a working regex although I spent really much time. There's always at least one special case where my regex fails.
The best one I was able to create is:

```
:%s/^\([^#].*\)\n\([^#].*\)$/\1\r#auto comment\r\2/g
```

This one works perfectly fine (except for the first line), if I run it twice. But running it only once skips some lines, e.g. I get this result:

```
The quick
#a comment
brown
#auto comment
fox jumps
#another comment
over
#auto comment
the
lazy
#yet another comment
dog
```

Notice that there's no line inserted between "**the**" and "**lazy**". The reason for this is, that the term "the" is a part of the regex group and part of the replaced text and so it won't be parsed by regex again.

Is there any possibility (well I bet there is and I'm just not able to find it...) to solve this issue?
I realize that checking the first line is another problem, too. It would be great if this could be recognized, too, however this is currently not my main focus of attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look-behind, `\@<!`, to ensure the previous line is not a comment.

```
%s/\(^#.*\n\)\@<!\_^[^#]/#auto comment\r&
```

For more information see:

```
:h /\@<!
:h /\_^
:h s/\\&
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also tried using negative look-behind, but didn't know there are more options than "\@!". Seems I still have a lot to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `:%s/^\([^#].*\)/#auto comment\r\1/g`

Then run: `:%s/^\(#.*\)\n#.*/\1/g`

**OR** `:%s/^\([^#].*\)/#auto comment\r\1/g | %s/^\(#.*\)\n#.*/\1/g`

Comment: That puts an extra comment above all the lines that already have comments above them.

Comment: Then run this after `:%s/^\(#.*\)\n#.*/\1/g`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm really amazed how many responses I got in this short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^#\n]+\n#[\w ]+?\n[^\n]+(?:\n|$))|^([^\n]+\n)
```

Try this.Replace by `#auto comment\n$1$2`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/24

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution. Especially for this amazing link! This tools seems to be freaky handy for learning regex.

Comment: I gave it a try and noticed that it's not as flexible enough as I thought it would be. E.g. this won't work as desired if the comment line contains any non-word character, e.g. a dash. Furthermore, converting it to vim syntax isn't as easy as I thought it would be... You don't know about a tool which can convert the syntaxes of vim and pearl regex or a cheat-sheet?

Comment: @ThelloD dats an easy fix....include - in the character class....finding cheat sheat...will have to look for it